# Unexpected file transfer behaviour when building API using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Here is how my API works:

[image: How my API works]

You can find SeaweedFS [here on GitHub](https://github.com/chrislusf/seaweedfs).
And the code here:

```
// /drivers/seaweedfs.js Defines how API interacts with SeaweedFS
const { error } = require("console");
const http = require("http");
module.exports = class Weed {
  constructor(mserver) {
    this.mserver = new URL(mserver);
  }

  get(fileId) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let options = {
        hostname: this.mserver.hostname,
        port: this.mserver.port,
        method: "GET",
        path: `/${fileId}`,
        timeout: 6000,
      };
      let data;
      const fileReq = http.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`Statuscode ${res.statusCode}`);
        res.on("data", (response) => {
          data += response;
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
          resolve(data);
        });
      });
      fileReq.on("error", () => {
        console.error(error);
        reject();
      });
      fileReq.end();
    });
  }
};
```

```
// /routes/file.js An Express router
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Weed = require("../drivers/seaweedfs");
let weedClient = new Weed("http://localhost:60002");

router.get("/:fileId", (req, res) => {
    weedClient.get(req.params.fileId)
    .then(data=>{
        res.write(data)
        res.end()
    })
}
)

module.exports = router;
```

MongoDB driver not yet implemented.

When I try to GET a file(using Firefox, Hoppscotch says `Could not send request: Unable to reach the API endpoint. Check your network connection and try again.`), I get something whose MIME type is `application/octet-stream` for some reason. It's bigger than the original file. I know there must be some problems with my code, but I don't know where and how to fix it.

Comment: can you try changing your `let data;` to `let data = "";`? and then on your `router.get` request handle function change `res.write` to `res.send` and remove `res.end`. Let me know if it made any difference please.

Comment: @Menma Now I get binary text in utf8 using Firefox and the same error using Hopperscotch.

Comment: @Menma After reading expressjs docs I found that when pass in a ```Buffer``` to res.send() without specifying MIME type, the MIME type is automatically set to ```application/octet-stream```. Now I have set the correct MIME type, but the file seems corrupted. There's no issue when directly access the file on SeaweedFS volume server, so I think there is some modification going on when receive the response from FS.

Comment: Is the file you are trying to read not a text file? Maybe the file is being compressed before sent on response. Check the response headers to see if that's the case.